# Python subprocess output variable error; Variable not defined

Tags: python, bash

When running script to `ssh` and return `iostat` errors,

```
solaris_command = "iostat -en | awk 'NR>=3 && $4 > 0' | while read a b c d e; do echo $e,$a,$b,$c,$d; done"

for line in server_list:
    line_arr = line.split(',')
    if line_arr[0] == 'SunOS':
        ie = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "%s" % (line_arr[2]), "hostname"], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    output = ie.communicate()
```

Server list has values: `SunOS,4,xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,sunhost5...`

Error returned,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./iostat_err_check.py", line 59, in <module>
    output = ie.communicate()
NameError: name 'ie' is not defined
```

I'm not sure why the variable is not being initialized so that I can use.

The strange thing is it works for another check I'm doing

```
linux_command = """df -Ph | awk 'NR>=2' | while read a b C d e f; do echo $f, $e, $d; done"""
Solaris_command = """df -h | awk 'NR>=2' | while read a b C d e f; do echo $f, $e, $d; done"""

for line in server_list:
    line_arr = line.split(',')
    # No ssh for Daily Checks host
    if line_arr[2] == 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx':
        df = subprocess.Popen(linux_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=None, shell=True)
    elif line_arr[0] == 'Linux':
        df = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "%s" % (line_arr[2]), linux_command], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    elif line_arr[0] == 'SunOS':
        df = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "%s" % (line_arr[2]), solaris_command], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    output = df.communicate()
    output = (output[0].splitlines())
    for mount in output:
        data = ("%s,%s,%s,%s\n") % (date_code, line_arr[3], line_arr[2], mount)
        data_file.write(data)
    servers_processed += 1
```

Df is being initialized and can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are gating the `subprocess.Popen()` call:

```
if line_arr[0] == 'SunOS':
    ie = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "%s" % (line_arr[2]), "hostname"], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

but your *next* line is *always* executed:

```
output = ie.communicate()
```

`ie` is only defined if the `if` test matched, so you need to *indent* the `ie.communicate()` line to only execute if you actually created the `Popen()` object.

Comment: Apologies for the late response. Took your advice and got my script working. Thanks.